# Fetch Dynamic data with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to fetch Data when we select  value.
Here Is Jquery and html code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $('#colorselector').change(function(){
             $('.colors').hide();
             $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
         });
      });
 </script>
```

Now Here is Html.And This Code is working .

```
<select id="colorselector">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

But when I am trying to use this with dynamic PHP code this is not Working.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="address"> Select Product Kit</label>
    <select class="form-group" name="product kit" id="colorselector">
        @foreach($product as $productDeatails)
            <option value='{{$productDeatails->id}}'>{{$productDeatails->title}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <div id="{{$productDeatails->id}}" class="colors" style="display:none">{{$productDeatails->price}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @endforeach
</select>
<div id="{{$productDeatails->id}}" class="colors" style="display:none">{{$productDeatails->price}}
```

As you can see, the `foreach` has ended before you could print the hidden div HTML. Due to this, `$productDeatails` is out of scope now and is no longer available.

A solution is to run the `foreach` again to print the hidden divs in HTML like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="address"> Select Product Kit</label>
    <select class="form-group" name="product kit" id="colorselector">
        @foreach($product as $productDetails)
            <option value='{{ $productDetails->id }}'>{{ $productDetails->title}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @foreach($product as $productDetails)
        <div id="{{ $productDetails->id}}" class="colors" style="display:none">{{ $productDetails->price}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```